# Update numa tabela A de números distintos, usando tabela B de números repetidos

Tags: sql-update

Tenho uma tabela (A) de números distintos e preciso atualizar vários campos dessa tabela em função do numero distinto, só que a outra tabela (B) que vai servir para atualizar tem os números distintos repetidos, quando faço o update ele só pega um registro da tabela B

```
TABELA A                        
NUMERO          H00 H01 H02 H03 H04 H05
552135792058    0   0   0   0   0   0

TABELA B        H00 H01 H02 H03 H04 H05
552135792058    0   1   0   0   0   0
552135792058    0   0   1   0   0   0
552135792058    0   0   0   1   0   0
```

Quando faço o update ele só pega um dos registros da tabela B, como faço para ele pegar todos.

Segue a minha query

```
update NUMD set NUMD.H00 = N.H00 + I.H00, NUMD.H01 = N.H01 + I.H01, NUMD.H02 = N.H02 + I.H02,
       NUMD.H03 = N.H03 + I.H03, NUMD.H04 = N.H04 + I.H04, NUMD.H05 = N.H05 + I.H05
        FROM NUMD N INNER JOIN #TBLtmp I
        ON N.NUMERO COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = I.NUMERO COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o comando abaixo atenda a suas necessidades:

```
UPDATE NUMD set H00 = H00 + I.H00, H01 = H01 + I.H01, H02 = H02 + I.H02, H03 = H03 + I.H03, H04 = H04 + I.H04, H05 = H05 + I.H05
FROM  #TBLtmp I
WHERE NUMD.NUMERO COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = I.NUMERO COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

Comment: Rogerio, esse update não funciona, retorna a mesma coisa do que fiz. Um cursor demora dias para processar, sao milhoes de registros. Preciso dum update que resolva. Obg.

Comment: Por acaso seus campos NUMERO estão indexados?